# How do I sort Magento products in a specific category according to my order

Tags: product, category, magento-1

I want to sort Magento products on a list page for a specific category according to my given order. Can I have a text field in each product and give any number and my products in that specific category will sort according to it in ascending or descending.

I have tried Magento default sorting. I have added for about 5000+ products in different categories and I want to sort them according to my sort order.

Please tell me the possible solution?

Answer (score 7):

This is possible:

- Make an attribute `my_sort_attribute`
- Set *Used for Sorting in Product Listing* to *Yes*
- You can now make it the default sorting in *System -> Config -> Catalog -> Frontend*

Only hard thing is that there is no default option for ascending or descending. You will have to write/modify code for that.

Comment: Thanks For the Answer i have found it Go to Manage Categories and Then Open The Category whom Products you want to sort and then open category products Tab and on the right most column there is a Textfield where u can give sorting order to products and the products will be displayed accordingly.

Comment: Magento allows you to change the position when you’re sorting by default.

Go to: Catalog -> Manage Categories.
Select a Category.
Select the Category Products tab.
Change position

Comment: Magento is not having default sort for ascending or descending, you need to write code for sorting it according to your need.